# ¿Como llenar datos de listas dentro de listas en Java?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Tengo el siguiente request el cual debo de llenar desde java

```html
<codeRequest>
 <user>
  <id>123</id>
  <registro>
   <id>1</id>
   <pruebaA>
    <id>1</id>
    <elementoBase>PRUEBABASE1</elementoBase>
    <tipoA>
     <elemento1>
      <tipo>ABC</tipo>
      <cadena>SFSG34235WF32</cadena>
     </elemento1>
     <elemento2>
      <tipo>DEF</tipo>
      <cadena>DJRT64353GSDG></cadena>
     </elemento2>
    </tipoA>
   </pruebaA>
   <pruebaB>
    <id>2</id>
    <elementoBasePruebaB>PRUEBABASE2</elementoBasePruebaB>
    <imagenPrueba>
     <imagen>
      <formato>JPG</formato>
     </imagen>
    </imagenPrueba>
   </pruebaB>
  </registro>
 </user>
</codeRequest>
```

y estas son las clases que tengo para ello

```html
    public class CodeRequest {

      private User user;

    }

    public class User{

      private String id;
      private List<Registro> registro;
    }

    public class Registro{

      private id;
      private List<PruebaA> pruebaA;
      private List<PruebaB> pruebaB;
     
    }

    public class PruebaA{
       
       private id;
       private ElementoBase elemento;
       private TipoA tipoA;
       private TipoB tipoB;
     

    }

    private TipoA{

     String elemento1;
     String elemento2;


    }

 public class PruebaB{
   private id;
   private ElementoBasePruebaB elemento;
   private ImagenPrueba imagenPrueba;
   
 }
 
 public class ImagenPrueba{
 
  private Imagen imagen;
 }
 Ejecutar
```

Mi duda es como ir llenando la informacion a partir de esas clases, cual seria la estructura de ir armando los objetos??, es que manejan listas dentro de listas  y no se como usarlas para el llenado de la informacion, ojala puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Considero que las clases que tienen listas de agún tipo deben tener un método que adicione los elementos respectivos a sus listas

```
public class User(){
..
  public class adicionarRegistro(Registro registro){
    this.registro.add(rgistro);
  }
}

public class Registro(){
...
  public void adicionarPruebaA(PruebaA pruebaA){
    this.pruebaA.add(pruebaA);
  }
}
```

y desde la clase `CodeRequest` orquesta todo, algo como

```
public class CodeRequest(){
...
  public void procesar(){
    TipoA tipoA = new TipoA(String elemento1, String Elemento2);
    PruebaA pruebaA = new Prueba(tipoA, ...);
    Registro registro = new Registro(id); //algún id que requiera
    registro.adicionarPruebaA(pruebaA); //aca implementa el método creado
    this.user.adicionarRegistro(registro); //user es atributo de la clase
  }
}
```

Espero le ayude con su inquietud

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer, lo que necesitas es obtener una estructura en formato XML a partir de un POJO principal (`CodeRequest`), el cual incluye otros POJO o lista de POJO. Para conseguir esto, te recomiendo utilizar la librería `JAXB`. Primero debes incluir los `getters` y `setters` respectivos a cada atributo. Después, debes anotar la clase principal con `@XmlRootElement` y los atributos con `@XmlAttribute` o `@XmlElement`, segun el caso. Puedes encontrar información más amplia en el siguiente link [Convert Java Object to and from XML using JAXB](https://attacomsian.com/blog/jaxb-convert-java-object-to-from-xml#)

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class CodeRequest {

    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "user")
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }    
}
```

La clase User tiene un atributo de tipo List, el cual se instancia con un ArrayList.

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private List<Registro> registro;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Registro> getRegistro() {
        if (registro == null) {
            registro = new ArrayList<Registro>();
        }
        return registro;
    }

    public void setRegistro(List<Registro> registro) {
        this.registro = registro;
    }
}
```

Ejemplo de llenado de información de un objeto CodeRequest.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CodeRequest codeRequest = new CodeRequest();
    codeRequest.setUser(new User());
    codeRequest.getUser().setId("id");

    Registro registro = new Registro();
    registro.setId("idRegistro");
    registro.setPruebaA(null);
    registro.setPruebaB(null);

    codeRequest.getUser().getRegistro().add(registro);
}
```

Comment: mis clases ya se encuentran asi, quiza debi agregarlo, lo que no se es como setearle los datos que necesito, osea armar una lista o un for? no se como estructurarlo para ir haciendo el seteo

Comment: Para poblar las listas de objetos, primero debes crear una nueva instancia de la lista para el atributo tipo List (`new ArrayList<Registro>`). Despues crear instancias de Registro, y agregar los valores a cada atributo. Finalmente, ir agregando cada objeto de Registro a la lista (user.getRegistro().add(registro)).